# suffix -ems (in slangy/hip-hop context): what special meaning (if any) does it convey and how commonplace is it?

Tags: slang, suffixes, nicknames

One of Shaquille O'Neal's numerous nicknames is "Extra-Tallems".

It's mentioned in a text I've been asked to translate and I'm trying to be somewhat creative.

Any sort of informative background would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems to appear solely in (I know I got) Skillz. Do you have any wider usage examples you can include to demonstrate that it is a suffix with a currency within the culture and not just something created to maintain the flow in a particular set of lyrics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suffix seems to appear solely in (I know I got) Skillz. [Geoffrey Golden at Crave](http://www.craveonline.com/site/174176-hip-hop-that-time-forgot-shaqs-i-know-i-got-skillz#73xoulcwPqOMtvff.99) suggests that there is no reason for the addition of *ems* other than making the lines scan.

> “I dribble rhymes like Basketball-ems / people call me E.T. / (what's
>   that Shaq man?)/ Extra-Tallems” – Why did he add the “ems” to
>   Basketball and tall? Those words both rhyme and they’re real words.
>   Adding the “ems” makes everything nonsense. There was no better way to
>   make those lines scan, Def Jef?